# Apply function to all string variables in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to apply some function to all string variable in a Django template?

Just like `escape` is applied unless `safe` filter is specified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you check the docs on custom filters and tags. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @intelis , filters and tags should be applied explicitly. I want an implicit application: `{{ obj.description }}` - and my function should be applied just like auto escaping.